# Python function argument passed "between" calls

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

This is an example from the book "Introducing Python" by Bill Lubanovic illustrating some basics of user-defined functions:

```
def buggy(arg, result = []):
    result.append(arg)
    print(result)

buggy('a')
buggy('b')
```

The "expected" output is a list comprised only of `arg` in both cases, but after the second call one gets the list `['a', 'b']`, suggesting that `result` is being carried over to the next call.  Maybe this isn't surprising, but when I try to print this object it doesn't exist:

```
In [53]: def buggy(arg, result = []):
   ....:     result.append(arg)
   ....:     print(result)
   ....:     

In [54]: buggy('a')
['a']

In [55]: result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-a5b1e83cd027> in <module>()
----> 1 result

NameError: name 'result' is not defined

In [56]: buggy('b')
['a', 'b']
```

What exactly is going on here?  Is the issue that `result` doesn't exist outside the function, but somehow the second call of `buggy` "knows" about the `result` that was created by the first call and decides to use it as an argument?  The author doesn't really explain what's happening.